# Get the value of a specific weight of a model in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Say I want to get the value of a weight in a certain layer, of a certain node, and a certain weight leading up to that node from the previous layer. I don't want biases.
I can get the weights of the layer like so:

```
# Access the layer by name
layer = model.get_layer('hidden_vector_layer')
# Get the weight matrix (excluding biases)
weights = layer.kernel[0]
```

How do I then get the weights of a specific node from that, and a specific weight from that? Thanks in advance.